# Regex match and replace of IDs

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to do a match and replace of strings that follow these patterns:

```
text_text_text
text_text
text_123
```

Basically, alphanumeric and one or more underscores.

The replace will basically just take the match and add a bold tag to it.

I have this so far but it matches basically with most of the text in my content:

```
$description = preg_replace(
"~[[:alnum:]+_]+~",
"<b>\\0<\b>",
$description);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have `+` in the character set? I thought you just wanted to match letters, numbers, and underscore.

Comment: `$0` is preferred rather than `\\0`.

Comment: I've edited now to `~[[:alnum:]\_]+~` and the replacement with `<b>$0</b>`. However I'm still doing something very stupid and wrong since it keeps matching all the rest of the text too. How can I make the underscore mandatory and stop it at any space?

Comment: I expect that most of the text in your content is letters and numbers. Why shouldn't it match it?

Comment: Should it only match if there's at least one underscdore?

Comment: Yes, my objective is to only match strings that contain one or more underscores and bold them. The rest of the text shouldn't be matched. The delimitator for a string would be a space. So for example in the sentence: "This is an id text_123 and this is not", only **text_123** would be bolded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to match when there's at least one underscore, you have to make that a required character, not part of the character set.

```
$description = preg_replace('~([[:alnum:]]+_)+[[:alnum:]]+~', '<b>$0</b>', $description);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following and see if it meets your requirements:

```php
$description = preg_replace(
  '~(?:[[:alnum:]]+)(?:_[[:alnum:]]+)+~', 
  '<b>$0</b>', 
  $description
);
```

Explanation:

- `~` delimiter

  - `(?:` start of non-capturing group

    - `[` start character class

      - `[:alnum:]` match alphanumeric characters
    - `]` end character class
    - `+` match character class 1 or more times
  - `)` end non-capturing group
  - `(?:` start of non-capturing group

    - `_` match underscore
    - `[` start character class

      - `[:alnum:]` match alphanumeric characters
    - `]` end character class
    - `+` match character class 1 or more times
  - `)` end non-capturing group
  - `+` match non-capturing group 1 or more times
- `~` delimiter

---

[Online demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9763b3001cd26f2286db726f72b79e490066a180)

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanation!